# How to format string from bash script? - Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi, command

So, when you run `uptime`, you get the uptime of your pi, if you run `uptime -p`, you get `up 32 minutes`, how can I make it only output JUST the minutes i.e. `32`?

Comment: `uptime .... | grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]+'`

Comment: once the system has been up for awhile what do you plan on doing?  for example, what happens if `uptime -p` returns `up 1 day, 18 hours, 3 minutes`?

Comment: @Jetchisel, that command will really come in handy, now I'd like to make it output the hours:min i.e. `14:33`, how can I do that? considering the command you pasted returns a list, hours would be element 3, and minutes, 4. Also, is there any place I can learn how to format those shells scripts like you did? Yesterday I went around trying to find something, but nothing that helped, really.

Comment: `'[:[:digit:]]+'`

Comment: Ok, that outputs: https://imgur.com/a/WXRmGqM, still not what I meant, is it possible to just get the 2nd line from this?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
uptime -p | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

But if you have days/hours unlike your example, this snippet don't convert these in minutes. For this, consider:

```
uptime -p |
perl -ne '
    if (/^up (?<weeks>\d+) weeks, (?<hours>\d+) hours, (?<minutes>\d+) min/) {
        push @{ $data->{$_} }, $+{$_} for keys %+;
        print $data->{weeks}*168+$data->{hours}*60+$data->{minutes} . " mn\n";
    }
'
```